# Play background video in iphone App

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, video

I'm developing a iPhone app and need to play the animation video in the background. This video should run until the user touch's the screen of the app. Not exactly the screensaver but this should happen for the first time when the app is opened.

How can play the video file in the background and screen buttons on top of the video in the app?

Answer (score 1):

Add video player in your view of subview and your view must be a transparent layer makes.
your app delegate check the user coming first time or not.

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testVideo" ofType:@"mp4"];   

    MPMoviePlayerController *myPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
myPlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
myPlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
myPlayer.fullscreen = YES;
myPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
myPlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
myPlayer.contentURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[self.view addSubview:myPlayer.view];
[myPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `MPMoviePlayerController` as background and play the video,

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: video_url];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player.view setFrame: requiredFrame];
[self.view addSubview: player.view];
```

After that, add tap gesture to whole view and remove player on tap gesture method..